# Google Smart Lock fetches credentials even after deleting it

Tags: android, google-smartlockpasswords

I am using google smartlock in my android application. It seems like credentials are cached in the system. Here is what I do - 
1. Launch app and sign-in
2. Save password to GSL
3. Go to passwords.google.com and signin with the same gmail which was used to signin to the device.
4. Find entry made by the android app
5. Delete the entry.
6. Launch the app again and GSL still fetches the credential.

My question is how did GSL find the credential when there was none? Does it store it locally or in cache ?

Comment: Yes, the credential are cached on the device. If you delete it and wait a few minutes, does it work as expected?